# Django - User uploaded S3 files in the view

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

I have a page where users can upload PDF / image files to their profile. The model for these files is relativly straightforward:

```
class ResumeItemFile(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(ResumeItem, related_name='attachment_files')
    file = models.FileField(
    max_length=255, upload_to=RandomizedFilePath('resume_attachments'),
    verbose_name=_('Attachment'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Naam'), blank=True)
```

I am creating a view where all files linked to a profile (`item`) are gathered in a .zip file. I've got this working locally, but in production I run in the following error `NotImplementedError:  This backend doesn't support absolute paths.`

The main difference is that on production the mediafiles are served through S3

```
MEDIA_URL = 'https://******.s3.amazonaws.com/'
STATIC_URL = MEDIA_URL

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

In my view I created a list of the ResumeItemFile in the `attachments` variable, which is a list of dicts that look like this: `{'filename', ResumeItemFileObject}`

```
            for file in attachments:

                storage = DefaultStorage()
                filename = file[1]
                file_extension = str(file[0].file).split('.')[-1]
                file_object = storage.open(file[0].file.path, mode='rb')                   
                filename, file_object.read())
                file_object.close()
```

Though this works fine locally, on staging it crashes on the `file_object = storage.open(file[0].file.path, mode='rb')` line.

If the backend does not support absolute paths, how I am to select the correct file? Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` on production?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've updated my initial comment with the required information, but the STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that problem comes because in the s3boto storage class, the path() method is not implemented. As per the Django documentation,

> For storage systems that aren’t accessible from the local filesystem,
>   this will raise NotImplementedError instead.

Instead of `file.path` use `file.name` in your code.

```
# file_object = storage.open(file[0].file.path, mode='rb')    
file_object = storage.open(file[0].file.name, mode='rb')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the `File` object. It allows you to manipulate files in a largely Pythonic manner, but leverages the Django project's storage settings. In my case, this allows me to use local, on-disk storage locally and S3 in production:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/file/

This will abstract away a lot of the boilerplate you're writing. There is an example here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/files/#the-file-object

Good luck!

Comment: As an opinion based aside, I've had better luck with Django S3 Storage, if you're only using the S3 backend: https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage It is a simplified version of `django-storages` which only support one backend, S3.