# How to perform actions on files stored in S3 bucket?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

In a Django-based web sevrice I'm implementing storage for `FileField` objects in S3 bucket. Some of those files later are copied to temporary path in the service itself, generate some result archive and are instantly deleted from temporary storage.

Here's simplified version of one of models I have:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_image = models.ImageField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    some_file = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    ...
```

Where `PrivateMediaStorage` is very primitive `S3Boto3Storage` implementation:

```
class PrivateMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'private'
    default_acl = 'private'
    file_overwrite = False
    custom_domain = False
```

With this implmenetation files are being correctly uploaded to `S3` bucket.

At some point when service wants to use them (copy to temporary local storage):

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(...)
shutil.copy2(instance.some_image.name, ***some_temporary_path_at_the_server***)
shutil.copy2(instance.some_file.name, ***some_temporary_path_at_the_server***)
```

This action raises `FileNotFound` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/code/api/views.py", line 55, in get
    configuration.content_json.name,
  File "/code/passmaster/compressor.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.temporary_directory, self.temporary_path = self.create_temporary_path(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/code/passmaster/compressor.py", line 28, in create_temporary_path
    shutil.copy2(file, temporary_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 266, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'some_image_JkaNI0p.png'
[31/Dec/2019 10:54:33] "GET /v1/dummy-pass HTTP/1.1" 500 104554
```

Why is this happening and did I make a mistake in storage implementation or rather refer file paths incorrectly?

---

Side question:

From other related questions I already found out that `S3Boto3Storage` [does not provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785235/django-user-uploaded-s3-files-in-the-view) `.path()` method. I'm using both local and `S3` storages depending on whether I'm running local development env or deploying code to heroku. Is there a common pattern which can be used to address file path that works for both local and `S3` storage implementations?

Comment: You can't use `shutil.copy()`. That's for copying local files. Use the [File `Storage` API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/storage/#module-django.core.files.storage) to load the file contents into memory and then use a different `Storage` (`FileSystemStorage`) to write the contents at the location you want.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks for a hint! Can you link more specific explanation or documentation which explains how to do this? I can't understand how to do this based on Django documentation.

Comment: Use `open()` or `read()` and `save()` on an instance of the correct storage class. There's a brief example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#storage-objects)

Comment: @dirkgroten but shouldn't `django-storage` be handling this rather than me asking `storage` directly?

Comment: Sure, but you're trying to copy files from one storage to another. `django-storage` is used when you upload a file and you can just open the file from you model: `instance.some_image.open()` is using `django-storage` to read the file. But when you want to save locally, you have to use a different storage. `FileSystemStorage` is probably the one you need for that.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, I'm trying to copy file from `S3` to local storage, but so far I'm unable to read file from `S3`, no matter which attribute I'm using `name`, `path`, or `url` I'm unable to retrieve a file from S3.

Comment: But your file in S3 is a `FileField` on your model isn't it? Then the file is just `instance.image` assuming `image` is the name of the field. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205163/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-stan-redoute).

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543979/how-to-configure-aws4-s3-authorization-in-django

Comment: Your chat discussion led me to a conclusion.Thanks :)