# How to configure AWS4 S3 Authorization in Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I configurred `S3` bucket for `Frankfurt` region. Though my `Django`-based service is able to write files to the bucket, whenever it tried to read them there's `InvalidRequest` error telling to upgrate authorization mechanizm:

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
  <Message>
    The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
  </Message>
  <RequestId>17E9629D33BF1E24</RequestId>
  <HostId>
    ...
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

Is the cause for this error burried in my incorrect implementation of storage backend or is this caused by bucket not supporting older `AWS3` method of authorization?

How to configure `S3Boto3Storage` in Django to use `AWS4` authorization? I can't find any definitive documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the `S3Boto3Storage` backend, I'm assuming you're using django-storages rather than writing your own implementation. There's a setting that lets you specify which signature version to use, `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'` you can find the full list of settings for S3 here https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings